# Issue with if statement

Tags: objective-c

I'm having an issue with an `if` statement

I have an object called `enemy2` and I don’t want that object to run so I have used `setHidden = YES` and i was going to use the code

```
if(enemy2 setHidden: YES)
{

}
if(enemy2 setHidden: NO)
{

}
```

But its says its excepting ')' after the setHidden

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you need to test if the view is `hidden` and then set a new `hidden` value to the property?

Comment: I agree with Flex. I'm not sure how you have your code set up, but I don't foresee this turning out well...

Comment: @NSAutoReleasePool - your edit completely invalidated the question. If you want to correct the code in a question, add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([enemy2 setHidden: YES])
{

}
if([enemy2 setHidden: NO])
{

}
```

Comment: and what code will execute in this case? what is the point of the if statements?

Comment: This answer makes no sense;  assuming `setHidden:` is a standard setter method, it returns (void) and, thus, can't be used in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you correct the syntax, neither of these statements will probably execute. I think you want

```
if ([enemy2 hidden])
{
}
else
{
}
```

Using the getter, not the setter.

Comment: Probably should be `isHidden`. `BOOL` getters usually start with "is", "has", etc.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as `if([enemy2 setHidden: YES]) { }`
i.e inclue square brackets

Answer (score 1):

In objective-C you have to call method like this `[anObject method]`

So, `([enemy2 setHidden: YES])` instead of `(enemy2 setHidden: NO)`

Answer (score 1):

As **jrturton** suggested (also see my comment) you need to test against a bool value.

If I test the code (with LLVM Compiler)

```
if([enemy setHidden:YES]){

}
```

I receive a compile time error since `[self setHidden:YES]` returns a `void`.

> Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)

The correct approach could be the following, but it depends on what do you want to achieve.

```
if([enemy hidden]) {


}
else {


}
```

**Edit**

Based on **Jonathan Grynspan** report, if `enemy` is a subclass of `UIView` you should use `isHidden` instead of `hidden` since the getter in `UIView` class is defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden
```

Comment: isHidden is right, assuming enemy2 is a UIView subclass. Otherwise we don't know what it is.

Comment: @bbum Sorry, I don't understand..my code was only for test purposes...what is it wrong?

Comment: @bbum if you refer to code within if-else statement, ok I removed it since it was there only for a typo. thanks